# Distortion Light on Object

Tags: modeling, mirror-modifier

i got a trouble on the object when i click shade smooth it start appearing black and white between my model i am using Mirror Modifier does it effect ?

[image]

why does it have 2 square when i actually made 1 and mirror it can someone help me how to remove that thing which divide the box

Comment: did you check face orientation? in edit mode press `a` to select all faces and then `Shift`+`N`

Comment: idk what i just did i just click Shift+N and it says recalculate and i didnt check the box and somehow the distortion thing is gone thanks alot.